# ValueError("x and y must be the same size")

Tags: python, boosting

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence import partial_dependence, plot_partial_dependence
from sklearn import  metrics, model_selection
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
import warnings
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import ensemble



warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

train = pd.read_csv('E:/vishnu vardhan/EM19424AVN1007WRPYTH/data/data/train.csv (6)/train.csv')


test = pd.read_csv('E:/vishnu vardhan/EM19424AVN1007WRPYTH/data/data/test.csv (2)/test.csv')
test_labels=pd.read_csv('E:/vishnu vardhan/EM19424AVN1007WRPYTH/data/data/test_labels.csv/test_labels.csv')

print("\nTrain Data")
print("==========\n",train)
print("\nTest Data")
print("==========\n",test)
print("\nTest_labels Data")
print("================\n",test_labels)
sns.barplot(x='toxic', y='identity_hate', data=train);
plt.show()
print("\n\nTrain data shape:",train.shape)
print("\nTest data shape:",test.shape)
print("\nTestLabels data shape:",test_labels.shape)
print("\nCorrelation matrix")
print("==================")
plt.title('Correlation Matrix')

sns.heatmap(train.corr())
plt.show()

print("\n Data Descriptive")
print("================\n",train.describe())

xg_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:linear', colsample_bytree = 0.3, learning_rate = 0.1,
                max_depth = 5, alpha = 10, n_estimators = 10)
print("\nRegressor")
print("===========\n",xg_reg)


X = test_labels.iloc[:,1:6].values
Y = test_labels.iloc[:,6].values
#print("X value\n",X,"\n\nY value \n",Y)

# split data into train and test sets
seed = 7
test_size = 0.33
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("\n Classifier")
print("============\n",model)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))

params = {
    'n_estimators': 1,
    'max_depth': 1,
    'learning_rate': 1,
    'criterion': 'mse'
}

gradient_boosting_regressor = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)

gradient_boosting_regressor.fit(X, Y)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.title('Gradient Boosting model (1 estimators, Single tree split)')
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, gradient_boosting_regressor.predict(X), color='r')
plt.show()
```

While executing the above code this error occurs.

> "raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")"

I have `.csv` file with 1398 rows and 2 columns. I have taken 40% as a y_test set, as it is visible in the above code.

Comment: Please, post only the relevant lines. This might also help you to debug alone.

Comment: Please add the full traceback of your error to highlight where exactly in your code this error happens. Then try to reduce your code as @BlueSheepToken has suggested

Comment: Without the line number, we cannot really tell you what is wrong. But I highly suspect this line to be the cause `X = test_labels.iloc[:,1:6].values
Y = test_labels.iloc[:,6].values`

Comment: x and y are of differenct size 2d and 1d

Comment: check the shape of `x` AND `y` by `x.shape` AND `y.shape`